# Metro ui css responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, metro-ui-css

I am making a website using Metro UI css; been able to create the tile area and specify the individual tiles but i am having a problem making it responsive for mobile as some of the tiles extend away from the screen when it's with a smaller device.

Here is my code so far

```
    <body class="content" id="main">

    <div class="tile-area fg-white" style="height: 100%; max-height: 100% !important;">
        <h1 class="tile-area-title">HERMA</h1>

        <div class="tile-group double">
            <div class="tile-container">
                <div class="tile-wide bg-green fg-white" data-role="tile">
                    <div class="tile-content iconic">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile-wide bg-green fg-white" data-role="tile">
                    <div class="tile-content iconic">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile-wide bg-green fg-white" data-role="tile">
                    <div class="tile-content iconic">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./tile-group double -->

        <div class="tile-group double">
            <div class="tile-container">
                <div class="tile-large bg-green fg-white" data-role="tile">
                    <div class="tile-content iconic">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile-wide bg-green fg-white" data-role="tile">
                    <div class="tile-content iconic">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./tile-group double -->

        <div class="tile-group double">
            <div class="tile-container">
                <div class="tile-wide bg-green fg-white" data-role="tile">
                    <div class="tile-content iconic">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile-wide bg-green fg-white" data-role="tile">
                    <div class="tile-content iconic">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tile-wide bg-green fg-white" data-role="tile">
                    <div class="tile-content iconic">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</body>
```

and the css for the page

```
.content:before
{
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;

    display: block;
    background-image: url("/img/dark-abstract-hd-wallpapers.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    data-role: fitImage;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}

.content
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#main
{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px)
{
    #main
    {
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

what's a way of making it responsive so there can be a scroll by the screen assuming i reduced my computer screen size or to make it responsive for mobile. thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use button "Toggle device" (top-left corner) in Chrome browser debug panel  which can be opened with F12 instead of changing screen resolution of whole computer. Then problem might go away.